# PopUpMenu Styling in winRT

Tags: windows-8, styles, microsoft-metro, popupmenu

I have created a `PopUpMenu` using http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/c25b6d/working-with-popup-menu-in-windows-store-apps/

Now I need to `style` the pop up menu. How to do so in Win8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, there are no way to styling popupMenu. If you want to styled flyouts, perhaps you should use popUp instead popupMenu.